How to display SVG icon received in base64 through img tag?
I have some troubles displaying svg/base64 encoded through img tag.
Here is the flow:

I am getting iconData (typeof string) from the server.
Want to display it in my component.

With p.1 no issues.
With p.2 I am getting broken image sign
Data JSON example:
{
    "icon": "PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMjgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyOCAyOCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTE1LjEyNSAyLjc1TDMuODc1IDE2LjI1SDE0TDEyLjg3NSAyNS4yNUwyNC4xMjUgMTEuNzVIMTRMMTUuMTI1IDIuNzVaIiBzdHJva2U9IiM0NzU0NjciIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMi4yNSIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=",
}

My parsing method:
parseIcon(icon: string) {
return `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${icon}`;
}
      

My template:
<div class="cell cell--icon">
  <img [src]="parseIcon(icon)" />
</div>

The icon string is valid, because if I would just try it through code like this it will do the trick.
 private _parseIconBase64TSVG(): void {
    const container: HTMLElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const svg: HTMLElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
      atob(this.iconData?.icon || ''),
      'text/xml'
    ).firstElementChild as HTMLElement;
    container.appendChild(svg);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.iconWrapper?.nativeElement, container);
  }

Is there a way to do it without renderer, just through plain string value?

Do you get any errors or warnings? I'd guess it's to do with untrusted values: https://angular.io/guide/security#trusting-safe-values.

Nope. There were no warnings (

For a Data URI, all characters that have meaning in a URI must be encoded
Using encodeURI :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI
Thus the # in your color must be encoded to %23
And you can include SVG in the IMG src attribute;
saves the CPU one conversion step from Base64 to SVG,
and is less code down the wire.


<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='28' height='28' viewBox='0 0 28 28' 
     fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
<path d='M15.125 2.75L3.875 16.25H14L12.875 25.25L24.125 11.75H14L15.125 2.75Z' 
      stroke='%23475467' stroke-width='2.25' stroke-linecap='round'
      stroke-linejoin='round'/>
</svg>">




Thanks for the answer. I have already found the solution.

The solution to my problem is to decode and then encode string I am recieving from/to base64. And then it will be parsed correctly.
Something like this:
cell: (icon: string) => {
      return `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(atob(icon))}`;
    }


encodeURI saves the CPU some work
